# vuejs this.$route issue with address bar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex, vue-resource

When I remove a parameter, It does not take effect in address bar. 
I tried following line to remove parameter from URL.

`delete this.$route.query[parameter_name];`

See below url, Notice following things.

1. In console query object is empty but address bar having all parameters.
2. I tried following lines to remove applicants and branches parameters from URL. It only effected in console as you can see query object is empty but URL is still there.

`delete this.$route.query['applicants'];`

`delete this.$route.query['branches'];`

But still address bar is having all removed params.

`donate#/?applicants=Female&branches=2207962`

Answer (score 2):

Using `delete` will delete the property but will not update the address bar.
You need to specify a redirect programmatically. See [Programmatic Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

You can use

```
this.$router.push('donate')
```

Or

```
this.$router.replace('donate')
```

to replace the current history entry (see comment from @thanksd)

Comment: I would use `this.$router.replace({ query: {} })`

Comment: Thanks, I added `replace` to the answer

Comment: Nice  @Thanksd, I understand. But I have case that I have 3 params in address bar, I want to remove 1 of them and want to keep 2 others. How I can I push or replace with other 2?

Comment: When I try `this.$router.push({path:'donate',query: filterObj}); ` It works fine but address look bad`http://project.seedout/donate#/donate?branches=2196379` Donate should be only single time.

Comment: Try with a slash: this.$router.push({ path: '/donate', query: filterObj })

Comment: Thanks My issue resolved bt pusing 2 time. 1st add empty param and them another. Means it was not updating address bar it same this.$route.query updated. So trickily change it 2 time. Its works

Answer (score 0):

This will work with `$router.push` or `$router.replace` to clear the query string.

Clear the query string inside a component lifecycle hook.

```
mounted() {
  this.$router.replace({ query: { '': null } });
}
```

Clear the query string on redirect.

```
$router.push({ path: 'url-path', query: { '': null } })
$router.replace({ path: 'url-path', query: { '': null } })
```

Remove old query string values and replace with new values.

```
$router.push({path: 'url-path', query: {'': null, lastname: 'Ever', firstname: 'Greatest'}})
$router.replace({ path: 'url-path', query: { '': null  token: 'coolToken' })
```